# Spring boot does not serve assets in resources folder when started with IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, vue.js

I am doing pretty much [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/04/spring-boot-vuejs/) tutorial. Basically you have a pom which controls two modules, the `frontend module` and the `backend module`.

Environment: `IDE: Intellij`, `spring-boot`, `Vue.js`

I initialized the `frontent module` using `vue init webpack frontend`. I added the pom to the `backend module` which copies the `assets` into the `backend module asset/public` folder. After `mvn clean install` all the content is in the `ressources/public` folder, but when I view the browsers sources it does not show any of them.

The resources folder looks like this:

```
└── resources
    ├── application.properties
    └── public
        ├── index.html
        └── static
            ├── css
            │   ├── app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css
            │   └── app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css.map
            └── js
                ├── app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js
                ├── app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js.map
                ├── manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js
                ├── manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map
                ├── vendor.42fc6c515ccdfe89bd76.js
                └── vendor.42fc6c515ccdfe89bd76.js.map
```

> I just noticed that running `java -jar backend/target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` solves the problem. But when I start the application using intellij it does not work out.

Full tree (directories only):

```
├── fileconverter
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── target
│   ├── frontend
│   │   ├── build
│   │   ├── config
│   │   ├── node
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── static
│   │   ├── target
│   │   └── test
│   └── target
│       ├── classes
│       └── test-classes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as I am having two modules `IntelliJ` used the classpath of the whole project instead of the `backend` module.

After changing the path in the configuration to: `Use classpath of module: backend` everything works fine.